# PHP Throws error when calling class method inside function

Tags: php

```
include "sys.php";

$logger = new logger();
$logger->write("Hello!");
```

This works. However,

```
include "sys.php";

$logger = new logger();

function test() {
    $logger->write("Hello!");
}

test();
```

This does not. The server crashes, error 500.

Why?

Comment: Because you don't know what is `function scope`.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm running the same code, just inside a function. It should work.

Comment: The method `test()` does not have `$logger` in scope, only variables passed as parameters, local variables and globals are visible

Answer (score 0):

`$logger` is not defined inside the function:

```
include "sys.php";

function test() {
    $logger = new logger();
    $logger->write("Hello!");
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

$logger is not available in test function scope as it is created outside test function.
You can declare it like this

```
    global $logger;
    $logger = new logger();
    function test() {
        global $logger;
        $logger->write("Hello!");
    }
    test();
```

Comment: what rhymes with global? "Evil".

Comment: $GLOBALS['logger'] = new logger();

This, for some reason, seems so wrong for me...

Comment: This might work, but it's even worse than not quite understanding the scope. Misuse of the `global` keyword and completely misses the point of object orentated programming.